# how can i execute whole code in akka actor without using the Thread.sleep command?

Tags: java, akka

i have a sample akka code

```
public class MainSystem {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("actor-system");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        final ActorRef actorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(SimpleActor.props(10));
        final ActorRef actorRef2 = actorSystem.actorOf(ActorTwo.props(10));
        System.out.println("actorref2:  "+actorRef2);

        actorRef2.tell(new Command("actor two cmd"), null);

        actorRef.tell(new Command("CMD 1"), null);
        actorRef.tell(new Command("CMD 2"), null);

        actorRef2.tell(new Command("actor two cmd   second"), null);


        actorRef.tell(new Command("CMD 3"), null);
        actorRef.tell(new Command("CMD 4"), null);
        actorRef.tell(new Command("CMD 5"), null);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        actorSystem.shutdown();
    }
}
```

If i avoid the last sleep statement, the code will not execute completely. How can i write program to complete all codes in actor without using sleep ?

Comment: send a message to the actor and ask it when it is done. receive the reply and then shut down.

Answer (score 2):

You could shutdown the system from inside the actor after the last message is received and processed, and wait for termination using`actorSystem.awaitTermination()`.

**Edit**

[Shut Down Patterns in Akka](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) is a nice blog explaining a shutdown pattern. You may not need this much now, but you will get a gist. The code is in scala, but its not that complicated.

Comment: Hi Johny, Thanks for the prompt response. I tried your code snippet and its working as expected. But now I am facing another problem. That is the code execution is stuck on that "awaitTermination" statement. I have a "actosSystem.shutdown();" statement after the "awaitTermination", but execution control not hitting that statement at alll. Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: That wont work. When you call `awaitTermination` on current thread, its actually awaiting termination. So, you cant call `shutdown` after that. You have to implement a logic, in such a way that you could shutdown the `ActorSystem` from your actor. You could send a `PoisonPill` after the last message and shutdown the `ActorSystem` from `Actor`'s `postStop`.